# How do I declare a function whose return type is deduced?

Tags: c++, auto, c++14

Consider this **C++1y** code ([LIVE EXAMPLE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=71b6b439065cbb52a47d72fee80e9f6d-0f11904895a20602a6e5ca9f4b5b0039)):

```
#include <iostream>

auto foo();

int main() {
    std::cout << foo();   // ERROR!
}

auto foo() {
    return 1234;
}
```

The compiler (GCC 4.8.1) generously shoots out this error:

> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>   main.cpp:8:18: error: use of ‘auto foo()’ before deduction of ‘auto’
>        std::cout << foo();
>                      ^

**How do I forward-declare `foo()` here?** Or maybe more appropriately, **is it possible to forward-declare `foo()`?**

---

I've also tried compiling code where I tried to declare `foo()` in the `.h` file, defined `foo()` just like the one above in a `.cpp` file, included the `.h` in my `main.cpp` file containing `int main()` and the call to `foo()`, and built them.

The same error occurred.

Comment: Are you sure you really need that? I don't think it's generally a good idea to create functions that return something so undefined, maybe you need to return instance of some abstract high-level class? No offence if you know what are you doing:)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the paper it was proposed in, [N3638](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3638.html), it is explicitly valid to do so.

Relevant snippet:

```
auto x = 5;                // OK: x has type int
const auto *v = &x, u = 6; // OK: v has type const int*, u has type const int
static auto y = 0.0;       // OK: y has type double
auto int r;                // error: auto is not a storage-class-specifier
auto f() -> int;           // OK: f returns int
auto g() { return 0.0; }   // OK: g returns double
auto h();                  // OK, h's return type will be deduced when it is defined
```

However it goes on to say:

> If the type of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type is needed to determine the type of an expression, the program is ill-formed. But once a return statement has been seen in a function, the return type deduced from that statement can be used in the rest of the function, including in other return statements.

```
auto n = n;            // error, n's type is unknown
auto f();
void g() { &f; }       // error, f's return type is unknown
auto sum(int i) {
  if (i == 1)
    return i;          // sum's return type is int
  else
    return sum(i-1)+i; // OK, sum's return type has been deduced
}
```

So the fact that you used it before it was defined causes it to error.