# type of pair that unordered map emplace returns

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I've a function which is calling `emplace()` method on an std unordered map container and I need to return the exact return value as given by `emplace()` call. I know it returns a `std::pair` of an iterator(whether new or old depends on successful operation) and a bool representing success. Earlier I was returning only the bool part like this:

```
auto result = map.emplace(std::make_pair(id, someObj));
return result.second;
```

and I knew return type was `bool`. But now I need to return the original `result` variable but I don't know it's type so what should I put in the function prototype in its class?

I tried using `typeid` method on iterator but it gave:

```
St4pairINSt8__detail14_Node_iteratorIS_IKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES7_ELb0ELb1EEEbE
```

as output.

Comment: You should consult some documentation. The Standard is the only definitive source, but a good approximation is: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

Comment: @GManNickG I tried finding an answer there but failed, only `Key` or `Iterator` terms were written there which I guess aren't exact types.

Comment: just return directly from emplace, which is returning `std::pair<iterator,bool>`. The interface is standard and make that explicitly in your wrapper. I would ask why the need for a wrapper of a standard function?

Comment: `std::pair<std::unordered_map<K,V>::iterator, bool>` where `K` and `V` are the actual types your map is templated on. You'll need to stick a `typename` in front of `std::unordered_map` if `K` and `V` are dependent names

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use C++11's trailing return type and `decltype` to accomplish this.  Doing that we would have a function like

```
auto some_function(some_parameters) -> decltype(map.emplace(id, someObj))
{
    return map.emplace(id, someObj);
}
```

Now the compiler will deduce the return type to be exactly the return of the `emplace` call.

If you can use C++14 or newer then you can use the auto return type deduction and simplify the code to

```
auto some_function(some_parameters)
{
    return map.emplace(id, someObj);
}
```

Here the compiler will deduce the return type of the function to the the type returned from the function by the return statement.  Do note that you cannot return different types in the function body this way as the compiler would not be able to deduce which type to use.

---

Note that in the above examples I did not use `std::make_pair` with `emplace`.  Unlike `insert` which expects a `pair` you can directly construct in `emplace`.

Comment: And with a new enough C++, you can omit the trailing return type for this case (where the compiler can deduce from the `return` statement).

Comment: @TobySpeight Just added that.  The Q is tagged C++11 so I left it out but the more I thought about it the more I figured I should let them know.  Thanks.

Comment: @RyanHaining Updated.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm using gcc 6.x compiler with c++14 flag but auto return type doesn't works for me. Probably because the function is a class method..

Comment: @hg_git Can you share a [mcve] on coliru?  It should work.

Comment: @NathanOliver coliru supports breaking files into .h and .cpp? Otherwise give me 10mins I'll try to repro and post the contents so you could try yourself. If it works my code will be much more readable haha.

Comment: @hg_git Unfortunately no.  Here is a [mcve](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee5a68aa81d2b152) that works.

Comment: @NathanOliver `error: use of 'auto A::proxyEmplace(int)' before deduction of 'auto'`  -  http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/sCHA4m3O7Xjde3E9

Comment: It doesn't even works with GCC HEAD 7.0 with c++1z flag on :|. The examples it works for are non realistic since they occur in single file...

Comment: @hg_git I looks like the auto return type only works the the declaration is the definition.  Trying to find something on that.

Comment: @hg_git It is not possible right now to use auto return deduction in a forward declared function.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268974/how-do-i-declare-a-function-whose-return-type-is-deduced) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20749951/how-do-i-deduce-auto-before-a-function-is-called)

Comment: @NathanOliver You can declare it, but the definition must be visible before any call